# Detecting if any values are within a certain value of each other - MATLAB

Tags: matlab

If I have:

```
a = [5000 8000 20000 22000 30000]';
```

Is there any quick way to detect if a given number is within - for example 5000 - of another and then remove both and replace them with the midpoint? Ideally I want to attach this to an IF statement but I really have no idea what sort of function or mathematical method could be used to do this.

The desired output would be for `a`:

```
   = [6500 21000 30000];
```

Comment: Is your array sorted?

Comment: By another one, you mean the next one?

Comment: And how do you have `30000` in the output?

Comment: Not necessarily the next one - if any number at all falls in line of another that's <5000 away, both are removed and the midpoint is taken. 30,000 remains in the output because nothing is within 5,000 of it. The array will not necessarily be sorted.

Comment: so what will be your output if input is [5000 8000 6000] for example? [6250] ?

Comment: What if you have more than one element with that `<5000 away` criteria. Something like this - `a = [5000 20000 22000 8000 7000 30000]`?

Comment: So it needs to basically scan along in 5000 point windows. If there's more than one within that window, it takes the lowest and highest point to create the mid point, ignoring all values in between. In the example above, the output would thus be [21000, 6500, 30000]

Comment: 6500 because it's the average of 5000 and 8000? But why does it go in the middle, not where the 5000 is?  Would [5000 8000 12000] be [6500, 10000]? What about [8000 5000 12000]? How does this ordering work?

Comment: The merging is sequential so for [5000, 8000, 12000] the answer would be 8500 because while 6500 is the midpoint between 5000 and 8000, 12000 is within 5000 of 8000, thus the midpoint between 5000 and 12000 is taken. A more expanded example would be [5000, 8000, 11000, 25000, 27000, 35000, 42000] with the output being: [8000, 26000, 35000, 42000].

Comment: @AnnaSchumann Do you care about the order of the elements in the output?

Comment: @Divakar the order in the output doesn't matter as long as every midpoint is correctly created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`accumarray`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) based approach might be best suited to solve it -

```
th = 5000      %// threshold to choose next elements (edit to specific input)
a = sort(a(:)) %// sort elements
matches = diff(a)>th
idx = cumsum([0 ; matches])+1 %// index each element with their group IDs
out = (accumarray(idx,a,[],@min) + accumarray(idx,a,[],@max))./2
   %// outputs are the midpoints of the min-max boundaries within each group
```

Comment: Interesting approach! When used with the input of a = [5000 7000 9000 10000 20000 22000 30000 36000]'; it provides the output of [7750 21000 30000 36000] rather than 7500. I suspect this was caused by the fact that i've included 9000 in the input instead of 8000 - the data may not be spaced equally but it would still have to take the midpoint of the lowest and highest number in the threshold window.

Comment: it was 8000 in the above example however in reality the data could be anything. See the comments I posted above.

Comment: @AnnaSchumann But I mean the average of `[5000 7000 9000 10000]` would be `7750`. So, for a input of `a = [5000 7000 9000 10000 20000 22000 30000 36000]'; `, the first element of the output has to be `7750` and not `7500`!

Comment: Yes - however I am not looking to average the values which fall within the threshold window. My apologies as I have not been that clear. By 'midpoint' I literally the midpoint between 10,000 and 5,000 - regardless of what all values in between are, these are ignored as 10,000 and 5,000 delimit the boundaries of the threshold window when th = 5000.

Comment: @AnnaSchumann Ah gotch ya!! Check out my edits. Needed just a minor change.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is spot on now and seems to be working regardless of the threshold value.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
a = [5000 8000 20000 22000 30000]'; %'// example data
th = 5000; %// example threshold
[ii, jj] = find(triu(abs(bsxfun(@minus, a, a.'))<=th, 1)); %'// find pairs of close points
a(ii) = (a(ii)+a(jj))/2; %// replace the first of each pair by the average
a(jj) = []; %// remove the second of each pair
```

Comment: I'm curious as to why when the input example is data = [5000 7000 8000 10000 20000 22000 30000 36000]'; and the threshold is set to 2000 that it's output is: [6000 21000 30000 36000] - why is it skipping some of the mid points?

Comment: @AnnaSchumann Shouldn't the first output be `7500`, the mean of [5000, 7000, 8000, 10000]?

Comment: @Divakar Yes with a threshold of 2000, that would be my expectation. The system works well with a threshold of 1000 or 5000. I'm not sure why it doesn't with intervening values.

Comment: @AnnaSchumann So, with `data = [5000 7000 8000 10000 20000 22000 30000 36000]'; ` and `threshold of 2000`, the output would be `[7500 21000 30000 36000]`?

Comment: @Divakar Yes when the threshold is 2000 or higher.

Comment: I started with bsxfun too, but then with the grouping thing coming in, I gave up, until I realized accumarray could have a play here!

Comment: @AnnaSchumann I've changed `<` to `<=`. Maybe that was the issue, I get the correct output with input `[5000 7000 8000 10000 20000 22000 30000 36000]`. Anyway, my code only averages _pairs_; it seems that's not what you want. Divakar's answer is more general

Answer (score 1):

In a simpler and more efficient way you could use 4 lines of code.

```
b = diff(a);
inds = find(abs(b) <= 5000);
a(inds) = (a(inds) + a(inds+1))/2;
a(inds+1) = [];
```

Try it. No sort, no bxsfun, no tricky things. With slight changes it can be also done as a function, Just replace `5000` with a threshold variable and do some cheks on the dimensions of the matrices (mostly cause of `diff`) and you are good to go.