# Detecting if values are within range of each other and taking a midpoint - MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Following on from: [Detecting if any values are within a certain value of each other - MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28745039/detecting-if-any-values-are-within-a-certain-value-of-each-other-matlab/28751795?noredirect=1#comment45786137_28751795)

I am currently using `randi` to generate a random number from which I then subtract and add a second number - generated using `poissrnd`:

```
for k=1:10
a = poissrnd(200,1);
b(k,1) = randi([1,20000]);
c(k,1:2) = [b(k,1)-a,b(k,1)+a];
end
c = sort(c);
```

`c` provides an output in this format:

```
823     1281
5260    5676
5372    5760
5379    5779
6808    7244
6869    7293
9203    9653
12197   12563
14411   14765
15302   15670
```

Which are essentially the boundaries +/- `a` around the point chosen in `b`.

I then want to set an additional variable (i.e. d = 2000) which is used as the threshold by which values are matched and then merged. The boundaries are taken into consideration for this - the output of the above value when d = 2000 would be:

```
1052
7456
13933
```

The boundaries 823-1281 are not within 2000 of any other value so the midpoint is taken - reflecting the original value. The next midpoint taken is between 5260 and 9653 because as you go along, each successive values is within 2000 of the one before it until 9653. The same logic is then applied to take the midpoint between 12197 and 15670.

Is there a quick and easy way to adapt the answer give in the linked question to deal with a 2 column format?

**EDIT (in order to make it clearer):**

The values held in `c` can be thought of as demarcating the boundaries of 'blocks' that sit on a line. Every single boundary is checked to see if anything lies within 2000 of it (the black lines).

[image]

As soon as any black line touches a red block, that entire red block is incorporated into the same merge block - in full. This is why the first midpoint value calculated is 1052 - nothing is touched by the two black lines emanating from the first two boundaries. However the next set of blocks all touch one another. This incorporates them all into the merge such that the midpoint is taken between 9653 and 5260 = 7456.

The block starting at 12197 is out of reach of it's preceding one so it remains separate. I've not shown all the blocks.

**EDIT 2 @Esteban:**

```
b =
849
1975
8336
9599
12057
12983
13193
13736
16887
18578

c =
662     1036
1764    2186
8148    8524
9386    9812
11843   12271
12809   13157
12995   13391
13543   13929
16687   17087
18361   18795
```

Your script then produces the result:

```
8980
12886
17741
```

When in fact it should be:

```
1424
8980
12886
17741
```

So it is just missing the first value - if no merge is occurring, the midpoint is just taken between the two values. Sometimes this seems to work - other times it doesn't.

For example here it works (when value is set to 1000 instead of 2000 as a test):

```
c = 
2333    2789
5595    6023
6236    6664
10332   10754
11425   11865
12506   12926
12678   13114
15105   15517
15425   15797
19490   19874

result = 
2561
6129
11723
15451
19682
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `5260 and 7293` because 7293 is within 2000 of 5260? Also, is `c` always sorted?

Comment: It's cumulative - so while you are correct that 7293 is within 2000 of 5260, 7293 is also within 2000 of 9203. As soon as it crosses into a pair of numbers, it uses the outer boundary. 7293 is not within 2000 of 9653 but this value is still used for the midpoint because 7293+2000 goes past 9203. Yes - c will always be sorted.

Comment: Also, how big could be your c, as in it's typical size in your application? Okay, I got one more query trying to understand the "algo" here - Shouldn't it be 12197 and 14765 instead because 14765 is 2000+ outside  of 12563?

Comment: `c` will never be that large - perhaps 50 pairs of numbers at maximum. The threshold (d = 2000) is assessed for every single number independently. 12197 is not within 2000 of 14411 but 12563 is - this causes the entire block held between 12197-12563 to be included in the chain of values to merge. This chain then stops whenever the check to see if the value it's currently checking has no value within 2000 of it. It's essentially the same as the answer you provided in the linked question except now it's using 2 columns instead of 1.

Comment: I should add that the values held between 12197-12563 (or any pair) can be considered an inseparable 'block' of points which either merges as a whole or does not at all.

Comment: Sorry! Been away for a while! So, in the first example of **EDIT 2**, shouldn't the first element of the output be `1424`, because it seems the first "group" of the output must go from `662 until 2186`?

Comment: Check out the posted solution? Really hoping that works! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works for you -

```
th = 2000   %// threshold

%// Column arrays
col1 = c(:,1)
col2 = c(:,2)

%// Position of "group" shifts
grp_changes = diff([col2(1:end-1,:) col1(2:end,:)],[],2)>th

%// Start and stop positions of shifts
stops = [grp_changes ; 1]
starts = [1 ; stops(1:end-1)]

%// Finally the mean of shift positions, which is the desired output
out = floor(mean([col1(starts~=0) col2(stops~=0)],2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure if it will work for all your samples... but this is the code I came up with which works with at least the data in your example:

```
value=2000;

indices = find(abs(c(2:end,1)-c(1:end-1,2))>value);
indices = vertcat(indices, length(c));

li = indices(1:end-1)+1;
ri = indices(2:end);
if li(1)==2
    li=vertcat(1,li);
    ri=vertcat(1,ri);
end

result = floor((c(ri,2)+c(li,1))/2)
```

it's not very clean and could surely be done in less lines, but it's easy to understand and it works, and since your `c` will be small, I dont see the need to further optimize this unless you will run it millions of time.

Comment: Interesting approach! It works with all data i've tested so far. It may be a little tricky as this is eventually going to go within another loop - and be run quite a large number of times.

Comment: Infact it's not working as intended upon further testing. It seems to be detecting the merges correctly but the result it returns is the mid-point between the last pair it matched in the merge chain - rather than the mid-point between start and end of the merge chain.

Comment: Could you post the data set in which it doesn't work and what the result should be?

Comment: The only thing I don't understand yet, is why in the data set that doesn't work, the missing mid-point is between (1764 and 2186) and not (662 - 2186)